# How do I add my labels when I use keras image_dataset_from_directory?

Tags: keras, tensorflow-datasets

I've been trying to load a dataset of images where I have the labels ordered in a separate csv file.

I tried:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    labels=labels
)
```

where labels is my labels in a Pandas Series

But I get the error that the truth value of a pandas series is ambiguous?

Could someone point my totally confused self in the right direction?

Thank you !

Comment: The documentation says about labels `a list/tuple of integer labels of the same size as the number of image files found in the directory.` So convert your Pandas series to a list. This should work.

Comment: But, personally, I always create a csv file including my image paths and their labels. This gives me more control over my dataset, instead of copying/moving the images all over the folders.

Comment: @Prefect thanks, I actually created a pandas dataframe with all the paths originally as I trained before just iterating over the images and labels, I imagined that this would be more efficient? As the old approach was slow as hell for large datasets

Comment: I am mostly working with `flow_from_dataframe` which creates an iterator with the given batch size. It should be also fine with large datasets.

Comment: @Prefect thank you so much! I totally overlooked that function, works like a charm.